# How to show youtube video's resolution(4k/8k) in non-search pages

Tags: youtube, tampermonkey

### What I want

We can see if a video is `4K` or `8K` ONLY in the search page of youtube via the `4K`/`8K` tag under the video, and I want to see the `4K`/`8K` tag in other pages(e.g. playlist page, video-play-page).

[image: 8K-tag-in-search-page]

[image: no-tag-in-video-play-page]

### What you may say

"Just click the `config icon` of video-play-page to get the maximum resolution of this video"

But this is not good, since the result of the `config icon` is incorrect(see blew explanation)!

### Explanation

- Visit this in PC's browser [youtube-search-URL](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Ultra+Europe+8K+180+VR)
- Then you'll see the first item in the search result is `Ultra Europe 8K 180 VR` with 2 tags `8K`/`VR180`
- Click that item, and you'll enter the video-play-page
- You will NOT find the `8k` tag in the video-play-page, and the maximum resolution u can find via the `config-icon` is only `2160s60 4K`, NO `8K` available.
- This is because this 8k video is a 3d SBS(side by side) video, which means the left part is 4k and the right part is 4k too. But since you are in PC monitor mode(mono mode), so only one side(`4K`) is available.

So is there any way to achieve that? Like an extension, or tamperMoney script? Thanks you guys.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more background details on your problem. Telling readers about your research, what you have already tried, and why it didn’t meet your needs will allow them to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

The render of such tags are made by YouTube and I have no idea how they set those tags - which, if you inspect the code of the page - those are rendered as "*badges*".

Extract from the search result:

```
{
  "videoRenderer": {
    "videoId": "Sv3yoyUOENU",
    [...]
    "title": {
      "runs": [
        {
          "text": "Ultra Europe 8K 180 VR"
        }
      ],
      [...]
    },
    [...]
    "badges": [
      {
        "metadataBadgeRenderer": {
          "style": "BADGE_STYLE_TYPE_SIMPLE",
          "label": "8K",
          "trackingParams": "CPIBENwwGAEiEwjYhsfMibH-AhXVw3IJHe4TBfw="
        }
      },
      {
        "metadataBadgeRenderer": {
          "style": "BADGE_STYLE_TYPE_SIMPLE",
          "label": "VR180",
          "trackingParams": "CPIBENwwGAEiEwjYhsfMibH-AhXVw3IJHe4TBfw="
        }
      }
    ],
    [...]
  }
}
```

See this [playlist sample](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkrObpDO1y36skClB1uv9yaEz_CBNPqsV) - which contains the video you show in your screenshot.

Compare the previous extraction with the response on said playlist:

Extract from the playlist:

```
{
  "playlistVideoRenderer": {
    "videoId": "cmULDIVQLNk",
    [...]
    "title": {
      "runs": [
        {
          "text": "The Swing Beans Live at The BuG in Virtual Reality"
        }
      ],
    },
    "index": {
      "simpleText": "1"
    },
    "shortBylineText": {
      "runs": [
        {
          "text": "Cynthia Cabello 360 VR Life ",
        }
      ]
    },
    "badges": [
      {
        "metadataBadgeRenderer": {
          "style": "BADGE_STYLE_TYPE_SIMPLE",
          "label": "VR180",
          "trackingParams": "CNICEMY0GAAiEwjguM7OjbH-AhV5w3IJHcSHDz4="
        }
      }
    ],
    [...]
  }
}
```

You can see that both items are rendered as `videoRenderer` and `playlistVideoRenderer` respectively - having different structures.

I believe that each object have their own restrictions/different structure and then, making the tags/badges shown differs between each object.

I doubt there is a easy way to get the same "view" of tags/badges in playlists - either with custom scripts or extensions.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Seems like the 4k/8k info is from the server side. OK, let's give up.